# Alternative to if-then-else with logical variables in R

Tags: r, if-statement

Let's say I have a function, which takes three logical arguments and returns a string indicating which of those were set to TRUE:

```
func_log <- function(option_1, option_2, option_3) {
    if (option_1 && option_2 && option_3) {
        opt <- "all"
    } else {
        if (option_1 && option_2) {
            opt <- "first two"
        } else {
            if (option_1 && option_3) {
                opt <- "first, last"
            } else {
                opt <- "last two"
            }
        }
    }
return(opt)
}
```

Is there a way to avoid constructing these if-else here? Using `switch` may be (would be grateful for an example then)? Any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
myfun <- function(...) which(c(...))

# examples
myfun(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)
# [1] 1 3
myfun(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)
# [1] 3 4 6
```

You could put names on these cases if you wanted to, like

```
mystrfun <- function(...) toString(c(letters,LETTERS)[myfun(...)])

mystrfun(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)
# [1] "a, c"
mystrfun(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)
# [1] "c, d, f"
```

Replace `c(letters,LETTERS)` with whatever your desired names are, and they'll get strung together.

Comment: And what if I indeed have to perform some sort of action depending on the combination of option_1/option_2/option_3?

Comment: @AS `if(identical(1:3,myfun(x,y,z))) do_stuff` and `if(identical(c(1L,3L),myfun(x,y,z))) do_other_stuff` ?

Answer (score 2):

Another idea...Manually enumerate the cases in a table, then `match` or `merge` to assign them:

```
mynames <- read.table(header=TRUE,colClasses="character",text="
case name
000  nope
001  last
011  lasttwo
010  middler
100  first
110  firsttwo
111  allyall
101  nomid")

myoddfun <- function(...) with(mynames,name[match(paste0(+c(...),collapse=""),case)])

myoddfun(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)
# [1] "nomid"
myoddfun(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)
# [1] "nope"
```